# FOR JSON throws error in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: json

I tried to follow the `FOR JSON` command in the SQL Server Management Studio, as shown in the following Microsoft website.

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882.aspx

This is the table that I am trying to access to:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oielf4pbmjjxynu/JSON1.jpg?dl=0

And this is the `FOR JSON` command that I am trying to use to export the data into JSON format similar to the Microsoft web site example.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j419fpn9ez67a4k/JSON2.jpg?dl=0

However, I kept getting error saying I have a syntax error and I really don't know where does the error coming from. As far as I know I have follow all the syntax correctly.

Please kindly help me up.

Thanks

Comment: Are you running SQL 2016? What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?

Comment: Nick, this is what I get:  Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64) 
 May 14 2014 18:34:29 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: `FOR JSON` is a **new feature** in the upcoming SQL Server **2016** release - it's **not available** on SQL Server 2012

Comment: Marc, thanks for your reply. So is there any easy way for me to do something like what "FOR JSON" will do which is helping me to convert data into JSON format so that I can port them into chart.js?

Comment: Since `FOR JSON` is not available in SQL Server 2012 - you'll have to do this in some other code, e.g. your front-end code has to read the relational data from SQL Server and then convert it into JSON

Comment: I typed T-SQL JSON into google and got this: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/

Comment: I had a similar problem.  FOR JSON is not available in my server, but i found an excellent solution in this link: https://devjef.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/using-for-xml-to-create-arrays-json-and-javascript/

Answer (score 3):

FOR JSON is available only in SQL server 2016. In older versions you should use some CLR libraries that format JSON such as http://www.json4sql.com/ or http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/74160/